# std_msgs / MultiArrayDimention

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i try to convert sonor range to 2D data and i follow this tutorial to do it [link text](https://github.com/alexsleat/projectChimaera/wiki/Other-Sensors-and-ROS-gmapping-(SLAM))
i found this error:

```
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/robot_setup_tf/src/sonarInjector.cpp:5:42: fatal error: std_msgs/MultiArrayDimention.h: No such file or directory
 #include "std_msgs/MultiArrayDimention.h"
                                          ^
compilation terminated.
robot_setup_tf/CMakeFiles/sonarInjector.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'robot_setup_tf/CMakeFiles/sonarInjector.dir/src/sonarInjector.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [robot_setup_tf/CMakeFiles/sonarInjector.dir/src/sonarInjector.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2893: recipe for target 'robot_setup_tf/CMakeFiles/sonarInjector.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [robot_setup_tf/CMakeFiles/sonarInjector.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

Can you help me please to find the solution?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232822/std_msgs-/-multiarraydimention/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a typo in your include:
try MultiArrayDimension.h , you typed a 't' in Dimension.

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/robot_setup_tf/src/sonarInjector.cpp:5:42: fatal error: std_msgs/MultiArrayDimention.h: No such file or directory
 #include "std_msgs/MultiArrayDimention.h"
```

The message is called `MultiArrayDimension` (note the `s`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-25**:
thank you very much